# Magento custom attribute filter

Tags: php, magento, attributes

I am a Magento developer. In my project I have added a custom attribute 'featured_product' to the table catalog_product, so that when clicking on any product from catalog/manage product , there will be an option for making the current product as a 'featured product'. Those featured products are displayed on the front end. Now in the product management grid, I want to develop a filter in terms of this 'featured product'. ie, There will be a check box or select box, and when we select 'featured product' from the select box and click on search, it will display all the featured products. How can I achieve this?

Comment: did you go through frontend properties when creating the attribute 'featured_product'?

Comment: 'Use in Quick Search', Use in Advanced Search and Use In Layered Navigation

Comment: I recommend this extension: https://github.com/tzyganu/GridEnhancer It allows you to add columns to the product grid, and others.

Comment: Finally I got the answer from this blog http://eglobeits.com/blog/magento/magento-create-featured-product-block-on-home-page/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the answer from this blog http://eglobeits.com/blog/magento/magento-create-featured-product-block-on-home-page/

Answer (score 0):

You have to override product grid in admin and add the column featured_product there. In that column you can sort all featured products.

Answer (score 0):

1. need add ypur custom attribute to grid collection.You can use observer event like this eav_collection_abstract_load_before or just rewrite this block Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid and update this method _prepareCollection().
2. add to method _prepareColumns next code like this

   `$this->addColumn('featured_product',
      array(
               'header'=> Mage::helper('your_modile')->__('Featured Product'),
               'width' => '60px',
               'index' => 'featured_product',
               'type'  => 'options',
               'options' => array('1' => 'Yes', '0' => 'No'),
       ));`